# Отображение тангенсойды

Tags: c

Вот программа для `sinx`:

```
#include(stdio.h);
#include(math.h);
#include(conio.h);
main()
{
    int i,j,n,m;
    float x,h; char z[80];
    x=0; h=3.14159/24;
    for (i=0;i<=48;i=i+1) {
        x=i*h;
        m=40*30*sin(x);
        for(j=0;j<m;j=j+1)
            printf(" ");
        printf("*\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Эта программа должна вывести на экран синусоиду в виде "*" звёздочек. Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне нужно изменить в этой проге, чтобы она выполнялась относительно `tgx`? т.е. чтобы вместо синусоиды была отображена тангенсойда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения задачи можно реализовать три подхода:

1. Зайти в Яндекс и ввести запрос - "функция вычисления тангенса на си". Ответ на вопрос получается мгновенно.
2. Поискать определение тригонометрических функций во встроенном help-е IDE, в котором вы работаете.
3. Заменить `sin(x)` в программе на `sin(x)/cos(x)`.

Но вначале надо отладить исходную программу. Потом попробовать заменить синус на косинус, убедиться что все работает.

А вот потом нужно понять, чем отличается функция синуса от тангенса - не хотите искать определение тангенса в Си, ну и ладно. Кстати, вот еще 4-й вариант - почему бы просто не найти файл math.h, на вашем диске и не посмотреть там определения функций.

Могу подсказать, что у каждой функции есть область определения и область изменения. В случае с синусом область изменения - от -1 до +1. А у тангенса? А чему равен тангенс pi/2? Механическая замена синуса на тангенс - не сработает!

Вот как должен выглядеть график синуса (gcc, MacOSX).

```
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <math.h>;
main()
{
    int i,j,n,m;
    float x,h; char z[80];
    x=0; h=3.14159/24;
    for (i=0;i<=48;i=i+1) {
        x=i*h;
        m=40+30*sin(x);
        for(j=0;j<m;j=j+1)
            printf(" ");
        printf("*\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: for(j=0;j<m;j=j+1)-а что означает эта запись?

Comment: цикл от 0 до m-1, т.е. m раз, в котором печатается пробел `printf(" ");`

Comment: А почему в этой записи: m=40+30*sin(x), стоят числа 40 и 30, а например не 20 и 10? или эти числа произвольно выбирают? и вообще конкретно что эта запись делает? указывает количество точек графика?

Comment: Масштаб то оси ординат. Т.е. значение синуса меняется от -1 до 1, масштабируется до [-30; 30] и сдвигается на 40, чтобы не было позиций левее начала строки (что невозможно). Т.е. график будет занимать позиции (по ширине) от 10 до 40+30=70

Comment: Для начала - разберитесь с масштабом осей.

Comment: По х от -пи<x<пи, а по у от -бесконечности до +бесконечности, я это уже пробовал подставлять во все стороны проги. Кто знает как делать эту программу, подскажи, что и где, конкретно нужно заменить. Вы ходите вокруг да около никакой конкретики, думаете я ничего не пробовал делать из того что вы написали, ВСЁ уже перепробовал и ничего. Мне уже завтра задание нужно это сдавать а тут такая неприятность.

Comment: Тебе и пытаются объяснить, как это делается. Главное - это алгоритм, а не код. Ты сам подумай, у синуса область изменения - от 1 до + 1 - в программе, которая приведена эта область отображается на  [-30,+30]. Для тангенса это не так. Но бесконечность ты не отобразишь. Поэтому нужно выбрать какой то произвольный порог, например -/+ 100. Тогда, если модуль значения тангенса вываливается за эти пределы ты рисуешь звездочку на левой или правой границе, если внутри, то как раньше.

m = tan(x)/100;
m = ( m < -1 ? -1 : (m > 1 ? 1 : m));
m = 40 + 30*m;

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто помогал в решении этой задачи.